# Homemade NFC scanning antenna?

Tags: nfc

I have been reading about NFC and was wondering If it was possible to make a NFC scanner antenna to read NFC signals from a further distance. I do understand that the N in NFC stands for Near that's why I'm asking if its possible.

I have read a few articles and [this one](https://terezapultarova.wordpress.com/2013/11/08/hacking-contactless-with-homemade-antennas-shortcomings-of-nfc/) seems the best. It is a study around capturing NFC data and they have also made a [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/9QjxwejBPHs) about this. I intend to do something similar but they don't describe the hardware to well.

If someone knows what I need or a better solution please let me know. As in this article they want it to be relatively cheap and small and this is what I want to. I would appreciate if you include the scanner and antenna details if you recommend equipment.

Comment: If you want to communicate between devices wirelessly, does it absolutely need to be NFC? Would something like IR or like a 2.4 or 5GHz transceiver also work?

Comment: Yes @0-60FPS , It needs to be NFC

Comment: Sorry @feetwet, I said "0-60FPS" responding to the guy who commented before me. I want to be able to scan NFC from afar as I am trying to test how easy it is to swipe credit cards for a personal project.